Unable to Open NpgsqlConnection: Error - Could Not Load File or Assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors'
I'm working on a C# application to fetch data from a PostgreSQL database using Npgsql. However, I encounter an error when trying to open the database connection. Here's the code I'm using:
public static DataTable FetchMasterData()
{
    NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionStringPostgreSQL);

    DataTable classMasterTbl = new DataTable();
    string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
    NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = null;

    try
    {
        sqlQuery = @"SELECT * FROM ClassMaster";
        npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlQuery, npgsqlConn);

        npgsqlConn.Open(); // Getting Error here

        NpgsqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(npgsqlCommand);
        dataAdapter.Fill(classMasterTbl);

        return classMasterTbl;
    }
    catch (Exception dalExce)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
        npgsqlCommand?.Dispose();
        npgsqlConn.Close();
    }
}

Error Message:
When I attempt to open the connection, I receive the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

App.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>     
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>

Packages.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>      
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>

.csProj
<Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"><HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>

Npgsql Package: I'm using Npgsql version 4.1.14.0
.NET Version: 4.6.1
Questions:

Why is the System.Numerics.Vectors assembly not being found?
How can I resolve this dependency issue?

Additional Information:
I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


Why is the System.Numerics.Vectors assembly not being found?

The package manager sees that you want 4.5.0, but the project file specifies 4.1.4. Since these do not match you get an error.
This can happen if there is a problem updating a package, or if there is a merge conflict that is incorrectly resolved. I don't think this is related to npgsql, but I might be wrong.

How can I resolve this dependency issue?

Edit the packages.config file or project file so that the versions match. I would probably recommend using 4.5.0. The app.config file should be updated automatically if you have "Auto generate binding redirects" turned on in the project file, but it is a good idea to double check.
You might also consider migrating to using PackageReference. In this format there is only a single reference to a package, so there should be no risk of version conflicts.

Thanks for your reply! Well, I already have 4.5.0 in packages.config
Already ON Auto generate binding redirects
